# Why does my django app sometimes takes ages to load a small page

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I have a very simple Django app running on a vps running Ubuntu 22.04, sometimes the page loads (for example the admin screen) take >10 seconds, while other times it's instant. I'm serving using Gunicorn, the website receives no traffic yet. What would be a good way to diagnose this? What are some common mistakes in config?

Comment: There are lot of variables to this problem, the network may be unstable, your VPS being hosted on a server with lot of others VPS, cache being used or not, etc ... To debug this you may try to watch logs from your django server, and use the network debugger from your navigator to see what are the ressources which take a lot of time being sent to it.

Comment: And use `top` or `htop` to see the processes.